# What is the PHP equivalent of Javascript's Date.UTC command?

Tags: php, javascript, timestamp

How can I say this Javascript in PHP:

```
var ts=Date.UTC(1985,1,22);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP's online docs are very useful: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

`mktime` takes args `hour`,`minute`,`second`,`month`,`day`,`year`.

```
$ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 22, 1985);
```

`Date.UTC` returns milliseconds whereas `mktime` returns seconds, so if you still want milliseconds, multiply by 1000.

Answer (score 6):

```
$date = new DateTime(NULL, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->setDate(1985, 1, 22);
$ts = $date->getTimestamp();
```

EDIT: Corrected time zone parameter.

Comment: Using this method you could then call `$ts->getTimestamp()` to get the timestamp (again in seconds since the epoch)

Comment: @bemace, yes, I found that just before I saw your comment.

Comment: Also, mktime uses GMT, whereas this method does provide actual UTC support in the rare case that the difference actually matters to you.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeZone, integer given

Answer (score 1):

```php
$ts = gmmktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 22, 1985) * 1000
```